# Remove model name from json results in cakephp 2.x

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using cakephp 2.x and returning some json data using the following; I would like to remove the model name User from the results so only the key and value is returned.

```
$this->set('_serialize', 'json');
```

and my results are returned in the following format;

```
[
{
    "User": {
        "fullname": "John Smith"
    }
},
{
    "User": {
        "fullname": "Jiles Smith"
    }
}
}
]
```

I am tried the following;

```
$json = json_encode(Set::extract('/User/.', $json));
```

but its returned like;

```
"[{\"fullname\":\"Ashley Smith\"},{\"fullname\":\"Leigh Smith\"},{\"fullname\":\"Charlie Chocolate\"}]"
```

Comment: post expected output ...

Comment: You seem to be using the JSON view, so remove the `json_encode` call, it's redundant...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@ndm posted the solution above. I would mark his answer as correct but I am unsure on how to.

Solution was to replace

```
$json = json_encode(Set::extract('/User/.', $json);
```

with

```
$json = Set::extract('/User/.', $json);
```

Comment: Comments cannot be accepted, only actual answers can, so just accept your own answer (possible after 48 hours), that's totally fine.